# Calling by Clicking the Number -- Android

Tags: android, html

I am trying to have it so that when the phone number is clicked, it makes a call.  The phone number is displaying correctly, but nothing happens when I click it.

Why is this not working?

```
tvInfo.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='tel:15555555555'><b>(555) 555-5555</b></a>"));
```

Let me know if more information is needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at [`Linkify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html).  Set the phone number normally with `setText`, and then use `Linkify`.

```
tvInfo.setText("(555)555-5555");
Linkify.addLinks(tvInfo, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 call.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>" + "9999999999" + "</u>"));
 call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            number = call.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```